# Limit Page to one Simultanious Request

Tags: php, apache, http, nginx, transactions

Using PHP or Apache (I'd also consider moving to Nginx if necessary), how can I make a page only be ran once at a time? If three requests come in at the same time, one would complete entirely, then the next, and then the next. At no time should the page be accessed by more than one request at a time.

Think of it like transactions! How can I achieve this? It should be one page per server, no user or IP.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do with the "busy" state on server? return an error right away or keep requests in waiting until the previous finishes?

If you just want the server to refuse content to the client, you can do it on both nginx and apache:

- [limit_req module for nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html)
- [using mod_security on apache](http://johnleach.co.uk/words/1073/rate-limiting-with-apache-and-mod-security)

The "tricky" part in your request is not to limit by an IP as people usually want, but globally per URI. I know it should be possible with mod_security bud I didn't do that myself but I have this configuration working for nginx:

```
http {
    #create a zone by $package id (my internal variable, similar to a vhost)
    limit_req_zone $packageid zone=heavy-stuff:10m rate=1r/s;

}
```

then later:

```
server {
  set $packageid some-id;
  location = /some-heavy-stuff {
                limit_req zone=heavy-stuff burst=1 nodelay;
  }
}
```

what it does for me is creating N limit zones, one for each of my servers. The zone is then used to count requests and allow only 1 per second.

Hope it helps

Comment: Would there be any way to not make it once per second, but rather once at a time? If the request takes a third of a second, it would allow three per second and if it takes 2 seconds, it would allow one per two seconds. While the server is busy, I don't have any problems with it just waiting for a response. Alternatively, I can output a set and defined value too. Creative solution using mod_security! +1 for that!

Comment: @NicholasYost can't say for mod_security, but AFAIK you can't with nginx without coding.

Answer (score 0):

If the same user gives the request from the same page then Use session_start() this will block the other requests until finish the first request

Example:

http://codingexplained.com/coding/php/solving-concurrent-request-blocking-in-php

If you want to block the request from different browser/client keep the entries in database and process it one by one.

Comment: I think there may be a misunderstanding. If I have three requests from three different users, I want one to execute entirely, then the next one, and finally the last one. I don't want to lock it based on the user because that will allow multiple users to each have up to one simultaneous request running. Because of the lock by server not user, sessions don't appear to be the solution unless I am misunderstanding how the server locks sessions.